# Windows Phone Store localized app title is always displayed in English

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-store, windows-phone-store

I tried to localize my app title using the [WP7 AppResLib DLL Generator](http://engine-designs.com/2011/08/17/wp7-appreslib-dll-generator/) and it partially work. After installing, the application title in the application list adjust well to the phone's language. For now two languages are supported: Polish and English.

Unfortunately, the application title in the Windows Phone Store is always displayed in English (no matter which language is set as a phone language or which version of the Store's website I visit).

In the root folder of the project I have the following files:

- AppResLib.dll
- AppResLib.dll.0409.mui (0409 - English (United States))
- AppResLib.dll.0415.mui (0415 - Polish (Poland))

And that's how my WMAppManifest.xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsphone/2012/deployment" AppPlatformVersion="8.0">
  <DefaultLanguage xmlns="" code="en-US" />
  <Languages xmlns="">
    <Language code="en-US" />
    <Language code="pl-PL" />
  </Languages>
 ...
</Deployment>
```

Can anyone tell me why it doesn't work as expected?

Remark:
Solution provided in the Microsoft's article [How to localize an app title for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967550%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) didn't worked for me, since I had problems with compiling the resource project both in VS2012 Express for Windows Phone or VS2013 for Windows.

Comment: Are you using the express edition of visual studio?

Comment: @Dave81: Yes, exactly. I used to use VS2012 Express for Windows Phone and now I'm using VS2013 Express for Windows.

Comment: I think it is not possible with express editions.